# Use Canvas as pad for multiple range inputs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build an html canvas pad that will allow a user to drag and drop a dot on the pad, which will then return two values (one for Y axis, and one for Y axis), which I can use to trigger effects using the web audio API.

I've already sorted out the web Audio API portion of the problem.

The User:

- Clicks and drags the dot to anywhere on the X/Y grid
- On Drop we will have an X & Y value (perhaps in hidden range inputs), that trigger eventListeners.
- The X value eventListener affects the `wet/dry` of the delay effect
- The Y value eventListener affects the `delay_time` of the delay effect

[image]

so far I've been able to create and render the canvas and circle, and add event listeners on the svg element and the window. With the idea being that I can detect when an event occurs inside the canvas and when that click event leaves the canvas.

```
// Draw SVG pad
function drawDelayPad() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('delayPad');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var rectangle = new Path2D();
  rectangle.rect(1, 1, 200, 200);

  var circle = new Path2D();
  circle.moveTo(150, 150);
  circle.arc(100, 35, 10, 0 , 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke(rectangle);
  ctx.fill(circle);
  }
}

// Listener on canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('delayPad');

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  console.log("click inside our canvas")
})

// Listener on document to check if we're outside the canvas
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
  console.log("outside our canvas")
});
```

So I think what I need to determine now is that when a click event does occur inside of the canvas, how far it is from the cirle, and if it does fall within the bounds of the circle, I should redraw it as long as the mousedown event is active.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's too broad. We won't do all for you, but a few concepts to help you : the canvas will only be the "visual output", your audio effects the "audio output". Both will be controlled by the same core routine, where you'll have an object with an x and y properties, updated on mousemove/whatever event that you'll listen on your page (be it on the canvas element or directly the page) which will be the "input". You don't need to have any `<input>` tag, simply store the info in an js object.

Comment: Hey @Kaiido, totally agree, working on it as we speak. I've added some code and I'll keep adding to the question as I make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create an object which will store your `x` and `y` values.
In below example I called it `pad`.

This object will serve both your canvas visualization, and your audio processing.
These are both *outputs* (respectively visual and audio), while the *input* will be user gesture (e.g mousemove).

The *inputs* update the `pad` object, while outputs *read* it.

[Note]: This example will only work in newest Chrome and Firefox since it uses `MediaElement.captureStream()` which is not yet widely implemented.

```js
const viz_out = canvas.getContext('2d');
let aud_out, mainVolume;

// our pad object holding the coordinates
const pad = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  down: false,
  rad: 10
};

let canvRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

function mousemove(event) {
  if (!aud_out || !pad.down) {
    return;
  }
  pad.x = event.clientX - canvRect.left;
  pad.y = canvRect.height - (event.clientY - canvRect.top); // inverts y axis
  // all actions are splitted
  updateViz();
  updateAud();
  updateLog();
}

viz_out.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 300) // invert y axis on the canvas too
// simply draws a circle where at our pad's coords
function updateViz() {
  viz_out.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  viz_out.beginPath();
  viz_out.arc(pad.x, pad.y, pad.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  viz_out.fill();
}
// You'll do it as you wish, here it just modifies a biquadFilter
function updateAud() {
  const default_freq = 350;
  const max_freq = 6000;
  const y_ratio = pad.y / 300;
  aud_out.frequency.value = (default_freq + (max_freq * y_ratio)) - default_freq;
  aud_out.Q.value = (pad.x / 300) * 10;
  mainVolume.value = 1 + ((pad.y + pad.x) / 75);
}

function updateLog() {
  log.textContent = `x:${~~pad.x} y:${~~pad.y}`;
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => pad.down = true);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => pad.down = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);


btn.onclick = e => {
  btn.textContent = 'stop';
  startLoadingAudio();
  btn.onclick = e => {
    mainVolume.value = 0;
  }
}

window.onscroll = window.onresize = e => canvRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

function startLoadingAudio() {
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.loop = true;
  audio.muted = true;
  audio.onloadedmetadata = e => {
    audio.play();
    const stream = audio.captureStream ? audio.captureStream() : audio.mozCaptureStream();
    initAudioProcessor(stream);
    updateLog();
    window.onscroll();
    updateViz();
  }
  // FF will "taint" the stream, even if the media is served with correct CORS...
  fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3").then(resp => resp.blob()).then(b => audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(b));

  function initAudioProcessor(stream) {
    var a_ctx = new AudioContext();
    var gainNode = a_ctx.createGain();
    var biquadFilter = a_ctx.createBiquadFilter();
    var source = a_ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.connect(biquadFilter);
    biquadFilter.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(a_ctx.destination);
    aud_out = biquadFilter;
    mainVolume = gainNode.gain;
    biquadFilter.type = "bandpass";
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
start
</button>
<pre id="log"></pre>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: That seems far cleaner than my solution. I'm going to give your solution a spin.

Comment: @TinusWagner, if you want to control multiple effects then an better impelmentation would be as in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tphbLuo3/

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice little solution that kind of confirms my suspicions surrounding a hit counter! All credit really goes to [rectangleWorld](http://rectangleworld.com/demos/SimpleDragging/SimpleDragging) since I was for the most part just able to modify the example they had available.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/tinusw/pen/aWGEzz)

```
// Draw SVG pad
function canvasApp(canvasID) {
  var theCanvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

  init();

  var numShapes;
  var shapes;
  var dragIndex;
  var dragging;
  var mouseX;
  var mouseY;
  var dragHoldX;
  var dragHoldY;

  function init() {
    numShapes = 1;
    shapes = [];

    makeShapes();

    drawScreen();

    theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
  }

  function makeShapes() {
    var i;
    var tempX;
    var tempY;
    var tempRad;
    var tempR;
    var tempG;
    var tempB;
    var tempColor;
    var tempShape;
    for (i = 0; i < numShapes; i++) {
      // My canvas element is 240x240
      tempRad = 10;
      tempX = 0 + tempRad;
      tempY = 240 - tempRad;
      tempR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      tempG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      tempB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      tempColor = "rgb(" + tempR + "," + tempG + "," + tempB + ")";
      tempShape = {
        x: tempX,
        y: tempY,
        rad: tempRad,
        color: tempColor
      };
      shapes.push(tempShape);
    }
  }

  function mouseDownListener(evt) {
    var i;
    //We are going to pay attention to the layering order of the objects so that if a mouse down occurs over more than object,
    //only the topmost one will be dragged.
    var highestIndex = -1;

    //getting mouse position correctly, being mindful of resizing that may have occured in the browser:
    var bRect = theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left) * (theCanvas.width / bRect.width);
    mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top) * (theCanvas.height / bRect.height);

    //find which shape was clicked
    for (i = 0; i < numShapes; i++) {
      if (hitTest(shapes[i], mouseX, mouseY)) {
        dragging = true;
        if (i > highestIndex) {
          //We will pay attention to the point on the object where the mouse is "holding" the object:
          dragHoldX = mouseX - shapes[i].x;
          dragHoldY = mouseY - shapes[i].y;
          highestIndex = i;
          dragIndex = i;
        }
      }
    }

    if (dragging) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
    }
    theCanvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);

    //code below prevents the mouse down from having an effect on the main browser window:
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    } //standard
    else if (evt.returnValue) {
      evt.returnValue = false;
    } //older IE
    return false;
  }

  function mouseUpListener(evt) {
    theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);
    if (dragging) {
      dragging = false;
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
    }
  }

  function mouseMoveListener(evt) {
    var posX;
    var posY;
    var shapeRad = shapes[dragIndex].rad;
    var minX = shapeRad;
    var maxX = theCanvas.width - shapeRad;
    var minY = shapeRad;
    var maxY = theCanvas.height - shapeRad;
    //getting mouse position correctly
    var bRect = theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left) * (theCanvas.width / bRect.width);
    mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top) * (theCanvas.height / bRect.height);

    // Divide by width of canvas and multiply to get percentage out of 100
    var DelayTime = ((mouseX / 240) * 100);
    // Invert returned value to get percentage out of 100
    var DelayFeedback = (100 - (mouseY / 240) * 100);

    // Set delay time as a portion of 2seconds
    delayEffect.delayTime.value = DelayTime / 100 * 2.0;
    // set delay feedback gain as value of random number
    delayFeedback.gain.value = (DelayFeedback / 100 * 1.0);

    //clamp x and y positions to prevent object from dragging outside of canvas
    posX = mouseX - dragHoldX;
    posX = (posX < minX) ? minX : ((posX > maxX) ? maxX : posX);
    posY = mouseY - dragHoldY;
    posY = (posY < minY) ? minY : ((posY > maxY) ? maxY : posY);

    shapes[dragIndex].x = posX;
    shapes[dragIndex].y = posY;

    drawScreen();
  }

  function hitTest(shape, mx, my) {

    var dx;
    var dy;
    dx = mx - shape.x;
    dy = my - shape.y;

    //a "hit" will be registered if the distance away from the center is less than the radius of the circular object
    return (dx * dx + dy * dy < shape.rad * shape.rad);
  }

  function drawShapes() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < numShapes; i++) {
      context.fillStyle = shapes[i].color;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(shapes[i].x, shapes[i].y, shapes[i].rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }

  function drawScreen() {
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

    drawShapes();
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load", windowLoadHandler, false);

function windowLoadHandler() {
  canvasApp('delayPad');
}
```

There are still a few shortcomings, for instance the mouseMoveListener, although constricting the movement of the circle, will continue to increase your x & y values. Meaning you'll either have to use your existing listeners to check when the drag event has exited the circle, or much more simply, you could set an upper limit to your X and Y values.